# Convert AI file to PNG with imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I am not sure if it's possible. But this is what I did:

```
<?php

define("IMAGE_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/files/");

if ($fileInfo = $_FILES['file']) {

    if ($fileInfo['type'] === "application/illustrator") {

        if (!file_exists("files") || !is_dir("files")) {
            mkdir("files", 0777, true); 
        }

        $subDirs = scandir("files");
        $nextFolderNumber = 1;

        if (count($subDirs) > 2) {
            $nextFolderNumber = (int)end($subDirs) + 1;
        }

        if (!file_exists($nextFolderNumber) || !is_dir($nextFolderNumber)) {
            mkdir(IMAGE_PATH.$nextFolderNumber, 0777, true);
        }

        $folderNames = explode('.', $fileInfo['name']); 
        $filename = $nextFolderNumber.".".end($folderNames);
        move_uploaded_file($fileInfo['tmp_name'], IMAGE_PATH.$nextFolderNumber."/".$filename);
        $AIpath = IMAGE_PATH.$nextFolderNumber."/".$filename;
        convertoToPNG($AIpath, $nextFolderNumber);
    }
}

function convertoToPNG ($file, $folderNumber) {
    $image = new Imagick($file);
    $image->setIteratorIndex(0);
    $image->resizeImage(1080, 1080, Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
    # replace white background with fuchsia
    $image->floodFillPaintImage("rgb(255, 0, 255)", 2500, "rgb(255,255,255)", 0 , 0, false);
    #make fuchsia transparent
    $image->paintTransparentImage("rgb(255,0,255)", 0, 10);
    #set image format
    $image->setImageFormat('png');
    $image->writeImage(IMAGE_PATH.$folderNumber."/".$folderNumber."_1080x1080.png");

    $image->thumbnailImage(200, 200, true);
    $image->writeImage(IMAGE_PATH.$folderNumber."/".$folderNumber."_200x200.png");
    $image->destroy();
}
```

I am getting an error this way: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: not authorized '/var/www/html/pngconverter/files/8/8.ai' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412`. 
Will be thankful for every advice! There is nothing much I can explain here. Just uploading `.ai` file and want to convert it to `.png`. That's all. I know there is other questions similar to mine but didn't find solution there.

Comment: AI is not supported by imagemagic. You can try with eps but that needs ghostscript.